# code for adding up the digits of a number in C not working

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, digits

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int num,a;
    a = 0;
    num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while (i > 5){

        a = a + num % 10;
        num = num/10 ;
        i = i + 1;

    }

    printf("sum : %d\n", a);

}
```

the output

> 11111

> sum : 0

I am using `gcc` preinstalled on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

edit : sorry i forgot to mention that initially a only wanted to add the digits of a five digit number, that is where the 5 came from, sorry
edit : sorry again I had to bother you guys for such a silly mistake, I typed greater than (>) instead of less than (<)

Comment: Your while loop condition is wrong.

Comment: So, your code _doesn't_ result in a [tag:syntax-error], does it? Also, simply read your code: `i = 0; while (i > 5) ...` - why would `i` be greater than 5 right after you set it equal to 0?

Comment: I guess `11111` should be the input. Instead of using the counter `i` in the loop you should change it to `while(num != 0)`

Comment: This sounds like an excellent opportunity to use a *debugger*.  Set a breakpoint at the start of your code, and step through each instruction, watching how the variables change.

Answer (score 3):

The condition of the while loop evaluates at once to false because the variable `i` was initialized by `0`.

```
i = 0;
while (i > 5){
```

Also it is unclear why there is used the magic number `5`.

You could just write for example

```
while ( num != 0 ){
    a = a + num % 10;
    num = num/10 ;
}
```

However your approach will work only for non-negative numbers. A more general approach can look for example the following way

```
while ( num != 0 ){
    a = a + ( num < 0  ? -( num % 10 ) : num % 10 );
    num = num/10 ;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const int Base = 10;
        int num = 0;
    
        printf( "Enter an integer number (0 - exit): " );
        
        if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1 || num == 0 ) break;
    
        int sum = 0;
    
        while ( num != 0 )
        {
            sum += num < 0 ? -( num % Base ) : ( num % Base );
            num /= Base;
        }
        
        printf( "The sum of digits of the entered number is %d\n", sum );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter an integer number (0 - exit): 12345
The sum of digits of the entered number is 15
Enter an integer number (0 - exit): -12345
The sum of digits of the entered number is 15
Enter an integer number (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: For negatives values, code could omit the `num < 0` test, use  `a = a + num % 10;` in the loop and then `a = abs(a)` afterwords.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `i` and loop condition should be `num > 0` (or != 0 if you want to handle negative digits with some other modifications):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int num,a;
    a = 0;
    num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while (num > 0){
        a += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    printf("sum : %d\n", a);

}
```